# Vaadin 23 Excel like grid

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I'm in the need of an Excel like grid in an attempt to convert an "application" written in Google Calc to a real application. I've got one implementation using Vaadin, but it (also) suffers from a long page construction. The screenshot below uses a CSS flex grid with individual divs, and given 6 weeks, there are over 5000 individual divs.

[image: screenshot]

Constructing this page takes over 20 seconds, not something users will be happy about. I'm working on a version based on a table, but it does not seem to improve much. In the end the same amount of cells need to be constructed, whether they are DIVs or TDs does not seem to matter much.

Is there a way to construct such a grid in a more speedy way? I'm more than happy to solve "where did the user click?" on the server side. To be aware of: besides the number of cells themselves, each also has specific content, so just getting a grid shown is not enough.

Comment: Each component (div, or something else) is managed by the server. So when you have 5000 of them it's quite slow. You need to reduce the number of components managed by the server. I can't give you a better answer since I don't know the requirements. But the idea is to try to combine some elements. You have an example of a table generated ( instead of each element one by one) here: https://cookbook.vaadin.com/grid-details-table. You can also create or own component. There is also a paid add-on: spreadsheet which seems to fit your needs. It's still in preview: https://vaadin.com/roadmap

Comment: Once the grid is shown the interaction is quick, so the framework is handling the number of cells quite okay. I found the table example you suggested as well, but the challenge is to update individual cells from the server; no idea how to do that. Since this is a test project to see how Vaadin fairs with this application (I also have a version using Axon, thymeleaf and event streaming over a websocket.) I'm not too keen on using paid components, but I would not mind giving it a try using a trial license or something.

Comment: While the framework can certainly handle that many components once they're rendered, it will inevitably take a while to render that many server-managed elements, as @Jean-ChristopheGueriaud said, so I do think that needs to be dealt with entirely on the client side. As you need to update the contents of those cells from the server side, I would suggest building e.g. the day-grid as a Lit component with an API for setting the value of a particular cell, and then building a Flow wrapper for that component (i.e. the same way as Vaadin components work).

Comment: > Once the grid is shown the interaction is quick, so the framework is handling the number of cells quite okay.

It generates a huge communication between the server and the client, probably few Mb for 5000 components. That's the reason of the slowness, once it's done, it's fast since you will interact with few components (not 500 at once). You can open the browser inspector and check the communication to see the size.

Comment: Please share the code, that reproduces the actual problem. As of now it's not even clear, what parts are server- and what are already client-side.

Comment: As mentioned in the actual post: these are all server side divs, laid out using CSS flexbox and some CSS classes to add color. I could create two loops that create 5000 divs, but that would not add much. I would be curious how the spreadsheet component performs with a sheet of this size. Otherwise it may be prudent to write an Angular version as well.

Comment: @Jean-ChristopheGueriaud can you put your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each component (div, or something else) is managed by the server. So when you have 5000 of them it's quite slow. You need to reduce the number of components managed by the server.

I can't give you a better answer since I don't know the requirements. But the idea is to try to combine some elements.

You have an example of a table generated ( instead of each element one by one) here: https://cookbook.vaadin.com/grid-details-table.

You can also create or own component. There is also a paid add-on: spreadsheet which seems to fit your needs. It's still in preview: https://vaadin.com/roadmap

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the complexity of the UI itself. Rendering 5000+ cells will be slow what ever method you use and what ever framework you use. There will be big amount of elements in the DOM and you need to load also lot of data upfront. And as you see the result is huge, and it wont fit most screens. So I would recommend further design of the UI. Is it really necessary to show all the weeks at once? Your UI's complexity will already reduce a lot if you show only one week at the time and add buttons to browse the weeks forwards and backwards. But even with that optimization you will have lot of columns. I would consider adding another browsing direction by day. Further knowledge of the actual purpose of the UI will naturally give more insight how to develop it further.

Comment: I cannot change the UI, planning is done is blocks of 6 weeks and planners requires the total overview in order see patterns and solve conflicts. There are indeed filter options, most notably to only show one user. That reduces the amount of cells significantly. Still the constructon time is past the 2 second limit that normally applies to a web request. I will let you know how long my pure thymeleaf version takes.

Comment: My current version in thymeleaf constructs the page in 7 seconds, 1/3 of the Vaadin version. I probably can optimize it some more.